# Polynomials in two noncommuting variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $F$ be a field. Let's suppose we have this ring 
$$F\langle x,y\rangle$$
when $xy\neq yx$ and the elements take this form
$$p\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i$$
where $c_i=x^{a_{1i}} y^{b_{1i}} x^{a_{2i}} y^{b_{2i}}\cdots x^{a_{m_i i}}y^{b_{m_i i}}$ (The length of the monomial and the exponents both depend on $i$).

I defined this function $\varphi:F\langle x,y\rangle\to F[x,y]$ in these monomials ($c_i$):

$$\varphi(c_i)=x^{\sum a_{ki}}y^{\sum b_{ki}}$$
(which means that I count the number of $x$s and $y$s and "group" them) and extend it as
$$\varphi\left(\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n \varphi(c_i)$$
for any polynomial.
Let's suppose it's a $F-algebra$ homomorphism. It's obvious that it's surjective. I want to prove that $\ker \varphi=\langle xy-yx\rangle$.
It's clear that for a multiple of $xy-yx$, 
$$\varphi(p(xy-yx))=\varphi(p)\varphi(xy-yx)=\varphi(p)(xy-xy)=\varphi(p)0=0$$
So $\langle xy-yx\rangle \subseteq \ker\varphi$. How can I prove the reverse inclusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algebra $F\langle x,y\rangle$ is the free $F$-algebra on two elements, whereas $F[x,y]$ is the free *commutative* $F$-algebra on two elements.

Let $I = \langle xy-yx\rangle$. You can show that $F\langle x,y\rangle /I$ has the universal property of $F[x,y]$ : if $A$ is commutative and $a,b\in A$, then there is a unique morphism $F\langle x,y\rangle\rightarrow A$ sending $x$ to $a$ and $y$ to $b$, and it necessarily factors through $I$.

So there is a unique $F$-algebra isomorphism from $F\langle x,y\rangle/I$ to $F[x,y]$ sending $x$ to $x$ and $y$ to $y$ : this is your morphism, since any morphism from $F\langle x,y\rangle$ is uniquely determined by the image of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I know this proves more, but I just wanted to prove that was the kernel of my morphism, without using much theory, since I'm new to the topic.

Comment: Honestly, I think it would be quite painful and convoluted to give a direct elementary proof, because $F\langle x,y\rangle$ is not a very nice ring to work in if you don't adopt the categorical point of view (ie use its universal property).

Comment: Ok. Then that would be it.

Comment: You can do a direct proof by first showing that every element of $F\langle x,y\rangle$ can be written in the form $f=\sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} x^i y^j + r$ with $a_{i,j} \in K$ and $r \in \langle xy-yx\rangle$. This can easily be done inductively for monomials, from which the general case follows. Then $\varphi(f) = \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} x^i y^j$ and hence $\varphi(f)=0$ if and only if $f=r \in \langle xy-yx \rangle$. However, the proof using the universal property is the more natural one.